# Changing layout to IE browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, user-interface

This question may sound subjective or in appropriate for SO but it does make sense for programmers like me (who doesn't have any knowledge of CSS).

I have a template which has css (around 300 lines), they are working fine on Firefox, Opera, Chrome and **IE10+**. In a practical world, I may not like IE but I need to be prepare for IE version 8 & 9. 
So, is there any easy & quick way to change my CSS to get compatible to IE without much interaction with CSS? 
Or
Is there any way I can paste my existing CSS to get the compatible IE converted CSS?

I am sorry if my question is not clear, I mean to ask that how can I convert my CSS code to IE versions? Is there any tool available online on which I can paste my code and select the destination IE version so it will create a CSS code for that IE version? Or do I have to write the code manually for each IE version?

*Note: My CSS code doesn't have any reference to other css framework like bootstrap, boilerplate etc.. *

Comment: Yeah, for sure, you can just load up a different stylesheet for less than IE9 like so: <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel='stylesheet' href='ie9-and-down.css'/><![endif]--> OR you can use IE specific css hacks, inside your main css file, check it here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Use additional css file specially for IE lower then 10. You can easily rewrite classes from your main CSS file in it. Include your new css file (for IE lower then 10) after your main css file:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-old.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear, I mean to ask that how can I convert my CSS code to IE versions? Is there any tool available online on which I can paste my code and select the destination IE version so it will create a CSS code for that IE version? Or do I have to write the code manually for each IE version?